# How to connect to alexa voice service with Android companion app on mobile phone

Tags: alexa-voice-service

I following the link to setup Android companion app:
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Mac#5b---build-and-run-an-android-companion-app-authentication

I try to connect to Alexa Voice Service with Android companion app on mobile phone but after I click the connect button, it throws the following exception.

I can do it with Android companion app on emulator with ip address https://10.0.2.2:8443.

I added "IP.3=192.168.0.102" (which is my mobile phone ip address) in the file javaclient/ssl.cnf. (Even cannot connect for ip address=10.0.2.2)

Also, I changed the provisioningMethod to "companionApp" in file javaclient/config.json.

Do anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.102 (port
>   8443): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) 03-26
>   22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err: 
>   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124) 03-26 22:30:19.580
>   13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 03-26
>   22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err: 
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452) 03-26
>   22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err: 
>   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884) 03-26 22:30:19.580
>   13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
>   03-26 22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
>   03-26 22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:79)
>   03-26 22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 03-26
>   22:30:19.580 13839-13839/com.amazon.alexa.avs.companion W/System.err: 
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)

Thanks!
Jack

Comment: Used a wrong ip address, changed a correct ip address is ok now!

Comment: Hi i am also trying to connect via android device. i have given my android device ip address (https://192.168.1.115:8443). it's throwing connection refuse error. Can you please explain me what went wrong.